# Which technology in java can be used to transfer lot of synchornous data between two different systems?

Tags: java, sockets, messaging

The requirement is, one system aggregates lot of data and that data gets constantly changed. Size of the data is something like around 100 rows of "Name" and "Price1", "Price2" so on till "Price10". Here names and prices keeps changing for every 20 milli seconds. 
Can you provide ideas on how to transfer the data between two different systems when these systems are co-hosted? One idea is to send the information via socket. I would like to know if anyone has any better ideas to transfer the information other than byte transfer over the TCP/IP sockets? I heard about kafka messages but they are not superior to TCP/IP socket. Appreciate your ideas and let me know if I shall improve the question in any manner.

Comment: "not superior to TCP/IP socket" Kafka (and messaging systems in general) solve a different problem (really, several problems). Feel free to write your own copy of multicast, but in the meantime I can write the entire system with enhanced reliability and monitoring capability in an afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [Java Messaging service](https://www.javatpoint.com/jms-tutorial) (JMS) which provides you publisher/subscriber architecture oriented messages. You will need JMS provider which is responsible for message management. Tutorial i have provided shows how to setup JMS provider using glassfish server, but you can simplify that process by using framework like spring boot which allows you to run servlet applications as JAR thanks to embedded servlet containers for example.